# How to emit server-side error and receive details about the error client-side, using Socket.IO?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Using socket.io, what is the prescribed method of emitting an error so that error information is sent to the client?

I have this:

```
socket.on('connection', function(socket) { 
  if (someError) {
    emit('error', 'there is a error...');
  }
};
```

I know that there is a way to do something like what I want by registering a middleware with socket.io, but I'm not sure what I would need to do from the middleware to transmit the error information back down to the client:

```
io.use(function(socket, next) {
  next(new Error('An error has occurred.'));
});
```

Thanks in advance for any constructive guidance.

Comment: Yeah we're gonna need more info than that. Do you want to throw an error on the client and send it to the server? Vice versa? Back up a level and tell us what your higher level goal is.

Comment: If there's a connection error then an event "error" is automatically fired. http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You appear to be emitting the error correctly on the server side, but you may also find [the following syntax/example of interest](http://www.nodewiz.biz/nodejs-error-handling-pattern/):

```
socket.on('connection', function(socket) { 
    if (someError) {
        this.emit('error', new Error('there is an error..'));
    }
};
```

On the client-side you would need an [`error`](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object)) handler, here is an example of an 'error' handler:

```
socket.on('error', function (data) {
    console.log(data || 'connect error - no data');
});
```

In this case, `data` should contain details about the error.

You do not need to register a middleware component for this behavior, this behavior exists out of the box.

**References:**

1. [Client API Manager Documentation, describing events and parameters.](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#manager(url:string,-opts:object))
2. [NodeWiz.biz article on Error Handling patterns in Node](http://www.nodewiz.biz/nodejs-error-handling-pattern/)